# Executar algo após ser inserido um número determinado de caracteres num EditText?

Tags: java, android, xml

Gostaria de saber como limitar caracteres e executar algo em seguida, no Android.

Por exemplo, numa `EditText` ou uma `TextView` digito 5 caracteres, ao digitar o quinto caractere executa um comando, por exemplo, ele apaga o que foi digitado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para fazer algo na altura em que é digitado qualquer coisa no EditText adicione um `TextChangedListener` a esse EditText

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

      if(s.length() == 5){
        editText.setText("");//Apaga o conteudo
        //Aqui faça o que pretende ou chame um método da sua Activity
      }
   }

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {

   }
  });
```

Comment: sua resposta ajudou :)

Answer (score 8):

Você pode limitar através da propriedade `android:maxLength` no XML do layout ou adicionando um `InputFilter` no `TextView`/`EditText`.

Exemplos:

**XML**

```
<TextView
        ...
        android:maxLength="5" />
```

**Código**

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_do_textview);
textView.setFilters( new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(5) } );
```

Comment: @Rodolfo Não entendi sua pergunta.

Comment: @Rodolfo Acabei deixando passar a parte do "executar algo em seguida" da sua pergunta! Dê uma olhada na resposta do ramaral.

Comment: essa é a que deveria ser a correta. Sem processamento desnecessário.